# Como controlar / restringir que los usuarios comenten

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Tengo mi proyecto de final de curso (en Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Web), en el cual permito valorar y comentar a los usuarios registrados diferentes tiendas de pequeño comercio.

La cosa está en que como hago para comprobar que un usuario ha comentado o no a un comercio? Lo que no quiero es que un usuario pueda comentar 10 veces en el mismo comercio, solo 1 vez para cada uno.

Necesito un poco de guía no hace falta que me pongáis código ni nada si queréis, es para saber por donde tirar ya que estoy un poco perdida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que tienes los comentarios en una tabla de mysql que tiene el id del comercio y el id del usuario, el enfoque mas simple que se me ocurre es modificar dicha tabla y agregarle un indice tipo *unique* entre el id de comercio y el id de usuario. Esto para garantizar desde el modelo que no puede haber mas de un comentario por usuario/comercio.

Luego, si ocurre un error al intentar ingresar un nuevo comentario, lo deberás atrapar/manejar para identificar que se trata de dicho error y mostrar un mensaje amistoso, tipo "Ya comentaste este comercio"

Por ultimo para el lado del cliente, al generar la pagina verificar si el usuario ya tiene comentarios en dicho comercio, lo ideal seria que el cuadro y botón para enviar el comentario estén invisibles.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportacion!!! Me va a servir de mucha ayuda ya que si los usuarios no estan registrados ya tengo deshabilitado que puedan comentar, asi que me queda un poquito de faena pero no tanto!!

Muchas gracias!!